# Angular Material - Date picker muda a data quando tiro o foco do input

Tags: angularjs, typescript, aplicação-web, datepicker, angular-material

estou enfrentando problemas no Angular. Estou usando o angular material para alguns /componentes e eu estou usando o datepicker. O meu date locale já é 'pt', aparece até o nome dos meses em portugues e tal. Mas quando eu digito no input 11/08/1997 e clico fora do input, ele muda para 08/11/1997. Já tentei de tudo aqui mas não consegui.

Comment: Poderia colocar um trecho do código para facilitar a compreensão do problema? Você está utilizando o momentjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver colocando isso no meu modulo:

```
import { MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material';
import { MomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

...

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
    useValue: {
      parse: {
        dateInput: ['l', 'LL'],
      },
      display: {
        dateInput: 'L',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
      },
    },
  }
]
```

e no meu componente do input

```
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material';
    ngOnInit() {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('pt-br');
  }
```